# strange sign in Magento (Frontend/Backend)

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database, forms

I have this Value in my page and database:

> Baden-Württemberg

But in my Backend and Frontend i get both:

> Baden-WÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¼rttemberg

[image]

Can somebody tell me where I should look for the wrong information?
I'm using UTF-8 encryption

Comment: where are you working?

Comment: are you using encoding ? it might be coming due to 'u' after 'W'

Comment: Magento Version 1.8.1.0 at page shape-star.com.
Why? or what is needed?

Comment: yes encodin utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

This currently looks like the output gets encoded multiple times. The 
`ü` => is normally `Ã¼`.

When you look at the end of the string you have that present. If you try to utf8 encode `Ã¼` again you would get something like `ÃÂ¼` which has some unprintable items in the middle however you now have your beginning and end. I think there is some other conversion happening in between.

Overall I would suggest trialling with the default theme and all extensions disabled first to confirm if this is a server/database configuration issue or something introduced by your theme. Next check that on the database level everything is UTF-8 and the values already present are also UTF-8 (simply changing the encoding I believe does not fix existing values so you would need to re-enter them).

If you have found a solution please answer your own question so others can benefit from it.